# How to stop `cargo clippy` from running on dependencies as well?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-clippy

I have a workspace with many crates. I want to run `cargo clippy` only one of of them them and not any of its dependencies.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Is this for speed reasons or because dependencies have lint errors you'd like to ignore?

Comment: because dependencies have lint errors you'd like to ignore

Comment: I've answered assuming you are talking about workspace path dependencies. Is that the case?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming based on your mention of a workspace that `cargo clippy --package mypackage` is wrongfully running on a path dependency of `mypackage` within the workspace.

Wrongful linting of path dependencies in workspaces is a known issue. Progress has been slow. Having looked deep into the trenches of GitHub issues, I'd say the best place to track this right now is [this clippy issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/3025), which is blocked by [this cargo issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8143).

---

This has been ongoing for a long time, too. [This issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/1066) originally reports it and a fix is made in `clippy-preview`, while the fix isn't possible for "normal" clippy. [This issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/3837) tracks migrating everyone to `clippy-preview`. But after much [discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/7382), these integration plans [are abandoned](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/3837#issuecomment-617413116) for [a new method](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8143), that abandons `clippy-preview` entirely which finally brings us to the state of matters today: the way that clippy interacts with cargo and rustc to do what it does needs to change to support this feature.